# Drop Foreign Key that does not exist?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, foreign-key

So I just tried to drop a foreign key constraint from a table which did not exist. Long story short, we had a script which looked for FK constraints from information_schema, it looked like this:

```
select constraint_name, table_name, referenced_table_name 
from information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS 
where table_name = 'X' or referenced_table_name = 'X';
```

Then iterated over all of the results like so:

```
ALTER TABLE X DROP FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT_NAME;
```

The query then got stuck for several minutes in *copying to tmp table* which blocked other inserts/updates with a metadata lock. The worst part? That constraint did not exist. The query we ran did not filter by schema....we had an virtually identical schema generated by our Django test runner which had the foreign key constraints. Our "main" schema did not have these constraints present. If we update that query to select the desired schema, it correctly returns 0 constraints.

So you're telling me MySQL will attempt to do this table alteration, copying this data to a temp table, and block other "production" queries from doing anything, for it to just fail with Does Not Exist? Shouldn't it validate the constraint exists BEFORE it alters the table??

Fwiw I'm using MySQL 5.7.33 (deployed through Amazon RDS).